# Java Compliator-error (OSX)

Tags: java, macos, compilation

I'm having a really weird error in my java compilator, which I don't find the solution of. I'm running OSX and having the newest Java version installed, I've tried to compile through the script editor (Sublime Test) and the Terminal, and both result in the same error.

The interesting is that I can compile this script without any errors on the school computer (Linux).

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Billettpris{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Oppgi din alder: ");

        int age = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        if(age < 12 || age > 67){
            System.out.println("Du reiser for halv pris, 25 kr.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Du reiser for full pris, 50 kr.");
        }

    }
}
```

Then I'm getting this error on compile:

```
 /Users/Daniel/Dropbox/Skole/INF1000/Obliger/Oblig 1/Billettpris.java:12: illegal character: \172
        if(age < 12 || age > 67){
                      ^
/Users/Daniel/Dropbox/Skole/INF1000/Obliger/Oblig 1/Billettpris.java:12: illegal character: \8224
        if(age < 12 || age > 67){
                       ^
/Users/Daniel/Dropbox/Skole/INF1000/Obliger/Oblig 1/Billettpris.java:12: ';' expected
        if(age < 12 || age > 67){
                        ^
/Users/Daniel/Dropbox/Skole/INF1000/Obliger/Oblig 1/Billettpris.java:12: illegal start of expression
        if(age < 12 || age > 67){
                            ^
/Users/Daniel/Dropbox/Skole/INF1000/Obliger/Oblig 1/Billettpris.java:12: ';' expected
        if(age < 12 || age > 67){
                             ^
/Users/Daniel/Dropbox/Skole/INF1000/Obliger/Oblig 1/Billettpris.java:12: illegal start of expression
        if(age < 12 || age > 67){
                                ^
/Users/Daniel/Dropbox/Skole/INF1000/Obliger/Oblig 1/Billettpris.java:12: ';' expected
        if(age < 12 || age > 67){
                                 ^
/Users/Daniel/Dropbox/Skole/INF1000/Obliger/Oblig 1/Billettpris.java:14: illegal start of type
        }else{
         ^
/Users/Daniel/Dropbox/Skole/INF1000/Obliger/Oblig 1/Billettpris.java:14: ';' expected
        }else{
             ^
/Users/Daniel/Dropbox/Skole/INF1000/Obliger/Oblig 1/Billettpris.java:15: <identifier> expected
            System.out.println("Du reiser for full pris, 50 kr.");
                              ^
/Users/Daniel/Dropbox/Skole/INF1000/Obliger/Oblig 1/Billettpris.java:15: illegal start of type
            System.out.println("Du reiser for full pris, 50 kr.");
                               ^
/Users/Daniel/Dropbox/Skole/INF1000/Obliger/Oblig 1/Billettpris.java:18: class, interface, or enum expected
    }
    ^
12 errors
[Finished in 1.8s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you pasted the code from an external source that has different character encoding. delete this line:

> if(age < 12 || age > 67){

and type it back character by character, without pasting anything this time. this worked for me in the past. if you don't get an error anymore for this line, proceed to the other lines and delete all the special characters { } ( ) | and " and type them back yourself.